# Union of intersection of B and A and intersection of B and A complementation

Tags: probability, set-theory

Due to my little knowledge in set theory, I simply don't know how the authors of Statistical Inference could make this highlighted statement [image]

Could someone please explain? What book should I read to have a better understanding of these type out-of-the-blue statements? Thanks.

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram: that will make it obvious.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. The authors warned against using Venn diagrams as they were not rigorous. I know it's difficult sometime without visualisation, but I feel that might bring my thinking and reasoning ability to higher level.

Comment: Venn diagrams are perfectly rigorous when correctly drawn.  Regardless, they can provide the insight you need as well as suggest rigorous algebraic demonstrations.  Insight is gained by using multiple tools and approaches, not by eschewing any technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads like this: Elements in $B$ consist of elements that are either in $A$ or $A^c$ (i.e. not in $A$). So, elements in both $A$ and $B$ fall in the set $A\cap B$, and elements in $B$ but not in $A$ fall in $B\cap A^c$. This is the all possible situations for elements in $B$.

Comment: Another great answer, @gunes! Was it your own logical reasoning or from established concepts/axioms? Could you please recommend a book that I should read to obtain these  fundamental concepts from? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can review Elementary Set Theory from Doris.